# Prove a group of order $2pq$ is solvable, $p\neq q$, $p,q>2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to use the Sylow theorems to prove the following.

Let $G$ be a group of order $2pq$, where $p>q>2$ are primes. Show that $G$ is solvable.

Now, I realize that If I can show either $n_p=1$ or $n_q=1$, then I can find a subgroup of order $pq$ which is normal (index 2).

Now, I use Sylow to show that either $n_q = 1$ or $n_q=2p$.

So we assume $n_q=2p$. We also learn from the Sylow theorems that $n_q=2p\equiv 1\mod q$

Now, my idea is to somehow use this to show $n_p=1$, but I am not seeing how to do this.

I realize that this question has been posted before, namely here:[Suppose $|G| = 2pq$. Does $G$ have a subgroup of order $pq$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113551/suppose-g-2pq-does-g-have-a-subgroup-of-order-pq?rq=1)
but I cannot understand this final step involving the modular arithmetic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove more generarily the following result.

**Lemma:** Let $G$ be a group with $2n$ elements. If $n$ is odd, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$.

**Proof:** This is a standard result and proof, one of the simplest and cutest application of Cayley theorem.

Recall the proof of the Cayley theorem:

For each $a \in G$ define $\phi_a : G \to G$ via $\phi_a(x)=ax$.

The mapping $a \to \phi_a$ defines an isomorphism between $G$ and the subgorup 
$$H:= \{ \phi_a : a \in G \} \leq S_{2n}$$
of $S_{2n}$.

By standard group theory, $G$ has an element $b$ of order $2$ [this follows from Cauchy's theorem, but it has a very standard proof using only elementary means].

Now, look at $\phi_b$. This needs to be an element on $S_{2n}$ of order $2$, thus it is the product of pairwise disjoint two-cycles. Since $\phi_b: G \to G$ has **no fixed points**, $\phi_b$ must be the product of exactly $n$ two-cycles. Finally, as $n$ is odd, it follows that $\phi_b$ is the product of an odd number of two-cycles, and hence an odd permutation.

The claim follows now immediately:

Consider the sign
$$\epsilon : H \to \{ \pm 1 \}$$
This is an onto (here is why we needed to argue that $H$ has an odd permutation) and hence by the first Isomorphism theorem, $\ker(\epsilon) = H \cap A_{2n}$ is a subgroup of $H$ of index 2.

Since $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that there is a normal subgroup of order $pq$, by the above link. Also, there is a useful result that characterizes derived subgroups: If $H \trianglelefteq G$ is such that $G/H$ is abelian, then $G'$ is contained in $H$. There is, $G'$ is the smaller subgroup with quotient abelian. If $H \le G$ has order $pq$, then $|G/H| = 2$ is abelian, hence, $G' \le H$.

Comment: My biggest problem is showing there is a subgroup of order pq.